# Как функции, объявленные внутри другой функции, могут обращаться друг к другу?

Tags: javascript

И почему такой способ не работает?

```
function set(div) {
        this.div = div;

        this.func = function() {
            alert("work!");
        }

        this.div.on("click", function(){
            this.func();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Э... чо? То есть я хотел сказать, сформулируйте вопрос нормально, отформатируйте код и сделайте его синтаксически валидным.

Answer (score 2):

Кусок кода из вопроса работает не так как задумано, потому что у "родительской" функции и вложенной в нее разный контекст вызова, разное значение this. Подробнее об этом можно почитать например [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods).

Поэтому можно запомнить контекст вызова "родительской" функции в локальной переменной к которой имеют доступ внутренние функции:

```
function set(div) {
    this.div = div;
    var _this = this;

    this.func = function() {
        alert("work!");
    }

    this.div.on("click", function() {
       _this.func();
    });
 }
```

Comment: да именно! )) это я имел введу. Спасибо ))

Comment: @modelfak, тогда пометьте пожалуйста ответ как принятый)

Answer (score 0):

> И почему такой способ не работает?

Потому что `this` внутри `.on()`, относится к `.on()` а не к `set()`. Это называется сокрытие `this`.
В таких случаях применяют дополнительную переменную, которую обычно называют `it`, `me`, `that` или подобными наименованиями.